# Grails 3 Vs Grails 4 - Dates and Timestamp

Tags: grails

I'm experimenting with upgrading my Grails 3 app to be Grails 4. In both cases, I'm using it with Java 8 and an Oracle database. I'm seeing differences in how dates are handled, and was trying to find out about what changed regarding dates, but haven't found anything (in the release notes, etc) regarding this. Is there any kind of blog-post/release-notes that someone can point me to regarding this? Or, explain the differences below?

Two examples

I use a function like this to get a date from Oracle

```
Date currentDateTime; // NOte this is a java.util.date
{$Sql.TIMESTAMP = call GetcurrentDateTime} {
            returnedDateTime -> currentDateTime =  returnedDateTime;
        }
```

In Grails 3, returnedDateTime  would always behave as a java.util.Date. I know the return param in the function-call is Sql.TIMESTAMP, but it would let me assign it to a Date variable, and then behave as a Date. But in Grails 4, it behaves as java.sql.Timestamp, even though it's declared as a Date variable.

Another example: 
In my views, I'll have a date picker that could look like this

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal" >
    <g:datePicker name="reportingPeriod" precision="month"
    value="${reportingPeriod}"
    default="none" noSelection="['':'']"
    />
</div>
```

In Grails 3, I can echo the value by doing this:

```
log.info("params.reportingPeriod: " + params.reportingPeriod);
```

It'll show a result that looks like this `params.reportingPeriod`: `Sun Dec 01 00:00:00 UTC 2019`

I can also assign

```
params.reportingPeriod
```

directly to a `java.util.Date` variable

But in Grails 4, the controller instead shows this

```
params.reportingPeriod: date.struct
```

and it doesn't properly directly assigned to a Date variable.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm running into the same issue migrating a 2.4.x app to 4.0 . Changing all the `params.someDate` calls to `params.getDate('someDate')` works, but there has to be a better way to do this than changing every reference to a date param in the app...

Comment: Nope.... It seems to be that we need to change the calls as you describe.